# how to monitor connections to sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, monitoring, sql-server-2016

I am using the following query to check and monitor connections to sql server

```
SELECT loginame, nt_username, hostname, hostprocess
,[Connections Count]=COUNT(*) 
FROM master..sysprocesses
GROUP BY loginame, nt_username, hostname, hostprocess
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, hostname
```

It works, but I always have **a row with blank `[loginame]` with a high connection count** and I am wondering why is that, what it means and more important how to find out **who is generating those connections?**

If I add `[program_name]` like in the following

```
SELECT [loginame], nt_username, hostname, hostprocess
,[Client Name]=[program_name]   
,[Connections Count]=COUNT(*) 
FROM master..sysprocesses
GROUP BY loginame, nt_username, hostname, hostprocess, [program_name]   
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, hostname
```

I can see `[program_name]` it's `EntityFramework` generating those connections, but why the row is without a `[loginame]`? Should it be listed with the connectionstring `[user id]`? Which is in the output of the query, in another row, with the expected `[loginame]` and a count for connections.

In practice it seems sql is showing EntityFramework connections twice, in one row with blank `[loginame]` and in another row with the expected `[loginame]`, but why?

UPDATE 1

As for comments, with this query:

```
SELECT login_name ,COUNT(session_id) AS session_count   
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions   
GROUP BY login_name;
```

I am also getting a row with blank login_name

Comment: Instead of trying queries at random, check the **docs**. They contain entire chapters on the subject and explain that you should use Extended events and DMVs instead of querying the tables directly

Comment: Besides, what you ask is already available in `Activity Monitor`. Did you check it?

Comment: Check for example [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql) which shows how to retrieve current sessions and links to related views

Comment: Why are you asking this (apart from using the *wrong* table)? EF doesn't leak connections. It doesn't generate unwanted connections either. It *does* use connection pooling to *reduce* the number of client connections needed and reuse connections for the same client. As for monitoring, what does the *relevant* view show? What does `Activity Monitor` show?

Comment: In `Activity Monitor` I can see exactly the same situation, I have those lines with blank login and Application EntityFramework, in Task State for those lines I have either Running or Suspended and in Command I have SELECT

Comment: If I query `sys.dm_exec_sessions` I get the same result, a row with a connection count and no login_name.

Comment: About **why I am asking**, is because I am trying to monitor the number of connections created by entity framework to identify any leak, since I have 5 applications connecting to the same sql server and same database I need to know the connection count for each application, and since each application is connecting with a different `user id` I thought was logical to count connections per login.

Comment: In `sys.dm_exec_sessions` the `login_name` column is sometimes blank. In that case you can check `original_login_name`. Maybe you're only interested in `original_login_name` anyway (what login the connection was made using, rather than the current login for the connection).

Comment: If you set `Application Name` in your connection string (either in your config file or via code before connecting) you'll find it much easier to track which apps have lots of connections. Instead of just seeing "Entity Framework" you can see something useful, e.g. in `sys.dm_exec_sessions.program_name`.